# tsql - While Loop issue using temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

Our DBA has changed a function to be a procedure, so I am amending some of my procedures to cater for this. I've come across a problem with this in one of my procedures where I have a while loop.

I populate my temp table from the new procedure (#DGContol), and then have the following while loop:

```
SELECT @MinRcd = MIN(RcdNum) FROM #PortfolioDisclosure 
SELECT @MaxRcd = MAX(RcdNum) FROM #PortfolioDisclosure 

SET @RcdNum = @MinRcd
WHILE @RcdNum <= @MaxRcd

BEGIN

    -- Temporarily assign values to variables
    SELECT
            @PortfolioGroup = PortfolioCode
        ,   @EndDateTime    = MaxPositionDate_DetailedDisclosure

    FROM  #PortfolioDisclosure
    WHERE RcdNum = @RcdNum


    INSERT INTO #PositionsTable
        SELECT


                fi.ID_ISIN                          AS [Fund_ISIN]                  
            ,   RTRIM(a.acct_id)                    AS [Internal_Portfolio_Code]    
            ,   a.acct_desc                         AS [Portfolio/Fund_Name]        
            ,   CONVERT(CHAR(11),p.as_of_tms,103)   AS [Portfolio_Date]         
            ,   a.alt_curr_cde                      AS [Portfolio_Base_Ccy]     
            ,   i.iss_desc                          AS [Security_Description]       
            ,   RTRIM(i.pref_iss_id)                AS [Security_ID SEDOL/Internal]
            ,   RTRIM(ia.iss_id)                    AS [Security_ID ISIN]           
            ,   i.denom_curr_cde                    AS [Denomination_Ccy]           

            ,   SUM(p.valval_alt_cmb_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY RTRIM(a.acct_id))      
                                                    AS [Total_Fund_Value]

            ,   p.orig_quantity                     AS [Shares/Par_Value]           
            ,   p.valval_alt_cmb_amt                AS [Market_Value]               
            ,   p.fld5_rte                          AS [Pct_of_NAV] 

            ,   SUM(CASE WHEN i.issue_cls1_cde = '010' THEN p.valval_alt_cmb_amt ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a.acct_id)      
                                                    AS [Cash/Cash_Equivalents]

            ,   i.inc_proj_cmb_rte                  AS [Coupon_Rate]                
            ,   CONVERT(CHAR(11),i.mat_exp_dte,103) AS [Maturity_Date]              


        FROM dw_position_dg AS p

            INNER JOIN #DGControl AS dgc -- [M]onthly, [M]ost recent position
                ON dgc.DataGrpCtlNum = p.data_grp_ctl_num

            INNER JOIN dw_ivw_acct AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON a.acct_id = p.acct_id

            INNER JOIN dw_issue_dg AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON i.instr_id = p.instr_id

            LEFT OUTER JOIN dw_issue_alt_id AS ia WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON ia.instr_id = i.instr_id
                AND ia.id_ctxt_typ = 'ISIN'

            INNER JOIN #PortfolioDisclosure AS fi
                ON fi.PortfolioCode = p.acct_id
                and fi.MaxPositionDate_DetailedDisclosure >= p.as_of_tms

        WHERE RTRIM(a.acct_id) NOT IN ( SELECT xref.internal_value FROM  dbo.DP_CrossReference as xref
                                        WHERE xref.Codeset_type_id = 10401 
                                        AND xref.Originator_id = 'DataVendorPortfolioExclusion')

            -- Clear down variable values
            SET @PortfolioGroup = NULL
            --SET @StartDateTime = NULL
            SET @EndDateTime = NULL

            -- Move to next record
            SET @RcdNum = @RcdNum + 1

END -- END WHILE LOOP
```

However this returns lots of duplicate records. If I replace the temp table #DGControl with the original function then I get the correct number of records.

I don't really know what the issue would be or how I could re code this while loop so that using the table #DGControl I get the correct number of records. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback.  i worked out the issue.  My code looks like the following now:

```
BEGIN

SELECT @MinRcd = MIN(RcdNum) FROM #PortfolioDisclosure 
SELECT @MaxRcd = MAX(RcdNum) FROM #PortfolioDisclosure 

SET @RcdNum = @MinRcd
WHILE @RcdNum <= @MaxRcd

BEGIN

    -- Temporarily assign values to variables
    SELECT
            @PortfolioGroup = PortfolioCode
        ,   @EndDateTime    = MaxPositionDate_DetailedDisclosure

    FROM  #PortfolioDisclosure
    WHERE RcdNum = @RcdNum

    -- Insert DGControl record into table based on the MaxPositionDate_DetailedDisclosure from Portfolio Disclosure function
    INSERT INTO #DGControl
        EXEC InfoPortal..usp_Generic_DGControl '', '', @PortfolioGroup, '1', @EndDateTime, @EndDateTime, @PeriodType, 'M', 'POSITION'    -- [M]onthly, [M]ost recent position

    -- Insert into #PositionsTable
    INSERT INTO #PositionsTable
        SELECT
                fi.ID_ISIN                          AS [Fund_ISIN]                  
            ,   RTRIM(a.acct_id)                    AS [Internal_Portfolio_Code]    
            ,   a.acct_desc                         AS [Portfolio/Fund_Name]        
            ,   CONVERT(CHAR(11),p.as_of_tms,103)   AS [Portfolio_Date]         
            ,   a.alt_curr_cde                      AS [Portfolio_Base_Ccy]     
            ,   i.iss_desc                          AS [Security_Description]       
            ,   RTRIM(i.pref_iss_id)                AS [Security_ID SEDOL/Internal]
            ,   RTRIM(ia.iss_id)                    AS [Security_ID ISIN]           
            ,   i.denom_curr_cde                    AS [Denomination_Ccy]           

            ,   SUM(p.valval_alt_cmb_amt) OVER (PARTITION BY RTRIM(a.acct_id))      
                                                    AS [Total_Fund_Value]

            ,   p.orig_quantity                     AS [Shares/Par_Value]           
            ,   p.valval_alt_cmb_amt                AS [Market_Value]               
            ,   p.fld5_rte                          AS [Pct_of_NAV] 

            ,   SUM(CASE WHEN i.issue_cls1_cde = '010' THEN p.valval_alt_cmb_amt ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY a.acct_id)      
                                                    AS [Cash/Cash_Equivalents]

            ,   i.inc_proj_cmb_rte                  AS [Coupon_Rate]                
            ,   CONVERT(CHAR(11),i.mat_exp_dte,103) AS [Maturity_Date]              

        FROM dw_position_dg AS p

            INNER JOIN #DGControl AS dgc
                ON dgc.DataGrpCtlNum = p.data_grp_ctl_num

            INNER JOIN dw_ivw_acct AS a WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON a.acct_id = p.acct_id

            INNER JOIN dw_issue_dg AS i WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON i.instr_id = p.instr_id

            LEFT OUTER JOIN dw_issue_alt_id AS ia WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON ia.instr_id = i.instr_id
                AND ia.id_ctxt_typ = 'ISIN'

            INNER JOIN #PortfolioDisclosure AS fi
                ON fi.PortfolioCode = p.acct_id

            -- Clear down variable values
            SET @PortfolioGroup = NULL
            --SET @StartDateTime = NULL
            SET @EndDateTime = NULL
            -- Clear down #DGControl table to allow new record to be inserted
            DELETE FROM #DGControl
            -- Move to next record
            SET @RcdNum = @RcdNum + 1

END -- END WHILE LOOP
```

Adding the execution of the stored proc usp_Generic_DGControl at the beginning and then clearing it down after each loop stopped the duplication of the records.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared the output of SELECT * FROM OldFunction(args..) with EXEC NewStoredProcedure args...? If so, does the data returned look the same or has the duplication crept in when the DBA refactored the function to a proc.

If so you may need to de dupe the output from the sp first then run it through your remaining code. In short, if you are using the same arguments for both but they give you different results then you'll need to go back to the DBA.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes i have checked this

Comment: yeah they're exactly the same.  just makes no sense why within a while loop the temp table brings back duplicates but with the function i get no duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using either of your local variables (@PortfolioGroup, @EndDateTime) in this code. It is just inserting the same record set N number of times. Also, I think you can write this as a single select query without using temp tables or while loops and it will make it less confusing.